# Custom Mesh issue in Roblox

Tags: blender, roblox

I'm creating a game in Roblox, and it's assets in Blender. I have done a stage for the lobby and I'm facing a strange issue here.

Here is the stage I've created in blender, it has four slopes.
[image: Stage created in Blender.]

Now two of the slopes are acting fine.

[image: Stage imported in Roblox.]

But other two slopes aren't acting fine...

[image: Stage imported in Roblox.]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mirroring the working part and deleting the faulty part? You could also turn off cancollide and make some invisible parts under it if nothing seems to work.

Comment: Well, Roblox physics sucks and I was thinking of same solution like yours. Make the stage property *cancollide* off and make invisible but with *cancollide* property true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  MeshPart you can check the property CollisionFidelty and change it. Roblox hitboxes suck for meshes. You can try use certain plugins to check the hitbox of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Click your Meshpart > Properties > CollisionFidelty > PreciseConvexDecomposition

This fixed all empty-space errors for me, hope it helps!